# Receiving error: unused argument () in R while using a package from GitHub

Tags: r, github

I have to download data from a webpage https://nsidc.org/data/g02158.
Now, I found a package in GitHub repository to do the same.
Link to GitHub Package:https://github.com/jpshanno/nohrsc

First, I tried running the following code:

```
install.packages("remotes")
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("jpshanno/nohrsc")
library(nohrsc)
rasters <- 
  nsa_get_snodas(region="North America", product = c("snow water equivalent", "snow melt"),
                 start.date = "2016-04-01",
                 end.date = "2016-04-03",
                 path = "snodas")
```

The error I received was:

```
Error in region %in% c("CONUS", "North America") : 
  object 'region' not found
Called from: region %in% c("CONUS", "North America")
```

Now, referring to the base function defined in https://github.com/jpshanno/nohrsc/blob/master/R/nsa_get_snodas.R, I made the following change in code:

library(nohrsc)

```
rasters <- 
  nsa_get_snodas(region="North America", product = c("snow water equivalent", "snow melt"),
                 start.date = "2016-04-01",
                 end.date = "2016-04-03",
                 region = "North America",
                 path = "snodas")
```

But, I again received error:

```
Error in nsa_get_snodas(region = "North America", product = c("snow water equivalent",  : 
  unused argument (region = "North America")
```

Comment: It seems to work for me? are you sure that you created the path directory? By doing this: `pip <- "E:/dissertation/dissertation"`, then `path = pip` rather than `path = "pip"`. Seems to work for me. Although, there may be conflicting packages in your enviroment preventing a successfull download, so try restarting R and only reloading those packages.

Comment: Hi. I tried this:pip <- "C:/Users/xyz1/Desktop/dld"
path = pip, and then rasters <- 
  nsa_get_snodas(product = c("snow water equivalent", "snow melt"),
                 start.date = "2016-04-01",
                 end.date = "2016-04-03",
                 region = "North America",
                 path = pip), But I still reveive the error "Error in nsa_get_snodas(product = c("snow water equivalent", "snow melt"),  : 
  unused argument (region = "North America")"

Comment: That’s my package, I will take a look on my end to see if I can spot anything that might be tripping it up on your machine. What OS are you using? It shouldn’t be an issue for this error, but I ad some windows vs Linux errors previously when it came to unzipping the archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working together, the OP and I solved the problem. There is a [Windows binary](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Ejpshanno/win_binaries/nohrsc.zip) available for the package that worked as expected. The installation notes have been edited to move the Windows Installation note to the top.